# Hazelcast not able to discover other nodes in Linux

Tags: java, linux, hazelcast

We have the following Hazelcast.xml file

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.11.xsd">
   <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/hazelcast-mancenter</management-center>
   <instance-name>DistributedCache</instance-name>
   <properties>
      <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j2</property>
   </properties>
   <network>
      <interfaces enabled="true">
         <interface>10.5.167.*</interface>
      </interfaces>
   </network>
</hazelcast>
```

`

We have two different servers `.10` and `.11`. When the application in both servers is started, a cluster is formed on port 5701. Here is the log output in both servers.

Server .10 log

`Local member in cluster: Member [10.5.167.10]:5701 Non local members in cluster: [] Cluster size: 1`

Server .11 log

`Local member in cluster: Member [10.5.167.11]:5701 Non local members in cluster: [] Cluster size: 1`

As can be seen Hazelcast is unable to discover the nodes in other servers (Non-local members is empty). There is no firewall between the two and there is also full connectivity on port 5701. We are able to telnet between both servers. Additionally in Windows we are able to observe that they are able to find each other, but not in Linux. That brings me to the question is there something we are missing here?

Additionally there is no mention of any differences when using tcp/ip Hazelcast discovery on Linux compare to windows in the documentation. Hazelcast version is 3.12.6

Comment: Check if multicast is enabled for your ethernet interface or not. For example type "$ ifconfig eth0" then look for MULTICAST in the output. Here is an example that explains it more. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25872/how-can-i-know-if-ip-multicast-is-enabled

Comment: seems like its enabled - "ifconfig -a
               ens192: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 150"  @OrçunÇolak - eth0 does not exists in this system so I tried -a instead.

Comment: If multicast is enabled you can test it with sockperf *on the server*: sockperf server -i 224.2.2.3 -p 54327
*on the client*: sockperf ping-pong -i 224.2.2.3 -p 54327. See this link https://serverfault.com/questions/294207/how-can-i-test-multicast-udp-connectivity-between-two-servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default multicast discovery is used in Hazelcast.
Try to switch to `tcp-ip` discovery instead.

```xml
   <network>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false"/>
            <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                <member-list>
                    <member>10.5.167.10</member>
                    <member>10.5.167.11</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
        </join>
   </network>
```

And your log message doesn't seem to be a Hazelcast original one. Usually you see ones such as:

```
Oct 27, 2022 8:40:53 AM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.ClusterService
INFO: [10.5.167.10]:5701 [dev] [3.12.6] 

Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [10.5.167.10]:5701 - 36651420-f623-4ac0-adc7-73326fba9fa8 this
    Member [10.5.167.11]:5701 - f41c88f0-4e7a-466d-897a-b222effe19d2
]
```

Comment: I will try changing to tcp-ip but this doesn't explain why it works in Windows but doesn't on Linux. Regarding the logging, actually I have that log too but we also have custom logs. In Either case cluster size is always 1.

Comment: Your environment might block multicast messages, or an additional custom multicast-discovery configuration might be necessary. 
BTW have you seen a similar message in the log?
Oct 27, 2022 10:50:01 AM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [192.168.1.15]:5701 [dev] [3.12.6] Creating MulticastJoiner

Comment: How can I check if my env is blocking multicast msgs? As mentioned already I do not have any firewall and there is full connectivity on both 5701 ports. Also I do not see that hazelcast message in log. But I also don't see that in my Windows logs either so not sure if I should expect to see it or not.

Comment: Also regarding with the going with the tcp/ip xml. Do I not need to provide interface configuration? As reading this link https://groups.google.com/g/hazelcast/c/b7nuV8FzYkk they suggest I should.

Comment: For multicast will confirm with admin team

Comment: The interfaces configuration is usually not necessary, but it shouldn't harm if you have it enabled (and properly configured). When you use a default discovery/join configuration (i.e. multicast), then you should see the "Creating MulticastJoiner." message in the log.